Scipy Optimizing with Constraints
I am trying to find the values for my x where the sum of the columns of my data_matrix matches the intial_sums.
However the results are: Variable 0: 1.0 Variable 1: 1.0 Final sums: [0. 4. 0. 2. 0.] Initial sums (should match final sums): [0 2 0 1 0]
Where the final sums are not correct at all.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

Example data for optimization:
data_matrix = np.array([
[-1114.75839, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
[+325.115366, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
])

Initial sums for constraints:
initial_sum = np.array([0, 2, 0, 1, 0])

def objective(x):
    return np.dot(data_matrix[:, 0], x)

def constraint_1(x):
    return np.dot(data_matrix[:, 2], x) - initial_sum[1]
 
def constraint_2(x):
    return np.dot(data_matrix[:, 4], x) - initial_sum[3]
 
cons = [
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_1},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint_2}
]
 
bounds = [(0, None) for _ in range(len(data_matrix))]

Running the optimization:
result = minimize(objective, np.ones(len(data_matrix)), method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, constraints=cons, tol=1e-6)
 
optimized_x = np.where(np.abs(result.x) < 1e-5, 0, result.x)
optimized_values = optimized_x.tolist()

Output results
for i in range(len(optimized_values)):
    print(f'Variable {i}: {optimized_values[i]}')

final_sums = np.dot(data_matrix[:, 1:6].T, optimized_x)
print(f'Final sums: {final_sums}')
print(f'Initial sums (should match final sums): {initial_sum}')`

I tried it with and without bounds and tried to play with the constraints.

I tried to make sense of your bizarre format. I think you should go through and convert this to a single script where the interjected descriptions are turned into # comments.

There's a lot in here that doesn't make any sense. Why does "initial sum" appear three times in the data input? It's impossible to wish for "the sum of the columns of my data_matrix to match the initial_sums", because neither of those variables change. One of the variables in that description needs to make reference to x.

Write out an example of numbers for x that you think satisfy your constraints, and I think a lot will be revealed.

Assuming that your problem is well-constructed (which I somewhat doubt in context), you should start by writing this like
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

objective_coefficients = -1114.75839, +325.115366
initial_sum = np.array((0, 2, 0, 1, 0))

A = np.repeat(
    np.atleast_2d(initial_sum),
    repeats=len(objective_coefficients),
    axis=0,
).T

'''
[0 0] * [x] = [0]
[2 2]   [x]   [2]
[0 0]         [0]
[1 1]         [1]
[0 0]         [0]
'''

result = milp(
    c=objective_coefficients,
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(
        A=A,
        lb=initial_sum, ub=initial_sum,
    ),
)
assert result.success
print(result.x)

[1. 0.]

which is equivalent to your constraint-based formulation but more narrowly defined and reliable. But really, those np.dot(data_matrix[:, 2], x) - initial_sum[1] just reduce to x.sum() == 1, so:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

objective_coefficients = -1114.75839, +325.115366

result = milp(
    c=objective_coefficients,
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(
        A=np.ones_like(objective_coefficients),
        lb=1, ub=1,
    ),
)
assert result.success
print(result.x)

which still produces
[1. 0.]

That in turn reduces to
import numpy as np

objective_coefficients = np.array((-1114.75839, +325.115366))
x = np.zeros_like(objective_coefficients)
x[objective_coefficients.argmin()] = 1

In other words, x at the index of the lowest objective coefficient will always be 1.
